# Is Prelude to Paradise the same song as one of Hunter x Hunter (2011)'s soundtrack?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

I recently listened to the song **[Prelude to Paradise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tGIFGCj_So)** by Immediate Music and I'm pretty sure that the beginning (until at least 00:45) is nearly exactly the same track as one of HxH's songs (OST 1 or 2). It's probably one of the Zoldyck Family's themes.

Am I wrong? If not, what song is it?

Finally, if I'm right, is there any link between those two? I'm pretty sure they are *extremely* similar (well, at least the beginning), but Prelude to Paradise came out more than 4 years ago....

Comment: Believe it was the Zoldyck Family theme Immediate Music - Prelude To Paradise. If I have some time ill look it up :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an exact match to this song searching through the OST's I will agree that it does seem familiar to the Zoldyck Family theme at about 20 seconds into the Zoldyck theme they sound very close but there is a difference. As far as for link there is no real way to tell other than to ask the composer of Prelude to Paradise. ref([HxH Zoldyck Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyoBQCzsYAM))